# Javascript if condition for NaN is not working

Tags: javascript

```
var suffix = "M";
console.log(Number(suffix));
if(Number(suffix) !== NaN) { console.log("this should not be printed");}
```

The if condition should return false, but it is returning true. why?

Comment: use `!isNaN(Number(suffix))` instead.

Comment: @nonzaprej why did that happen?

Comment: Your question was marked as a duplicate of another question. That other one has the explanation.